# How many packages are in the main repository?

Tags: repository

This sounds like it should be a fairly straightforward question to answer but I haven't found it yet, only figures of main + universe, which is various figures over 24,000 depending on release.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run the following command line:

```
for f in /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages; do 
  printf '%5d %s\n' $(grep '^Package: ' "$f" | wc -l) ${f##*/}
done | sort -n
```

that on my machine show the following output

```
27433 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_universe_binary-i386_Packages
 7768 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-i386_Packages
 1944 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages
  664 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
  632 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_main_binary-i386_Packages
  605 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages
  167 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages
   67 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages
   24 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
   21 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
   13 extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-i386_Packages
   12 archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-i386_Packages
   11 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages
   10 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
    6 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
    0 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
    0 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages
    0 it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages
```

Comment: Thanks for that command-fu.  7768 in oneiric main is quite impressive.  As is 1944 in oneiric-updates main.

Comment: You comment works on Ubuntu 12.04 too. Awesome solution.

Comment: 53000 for 18.10

Answer (score 2):

Each distribution is different. But you can get a good idea of what is available by using "aptitude" and looking at the numbers.

as an example (not installed packages 32180)

[image]

Comment: This is not the answer to the particular question.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it [here](https://repology.org/repositories) on repology.org.

Comment: Nice website, didn't know this! Has a nice very nice search function!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `Package` files are now `Package.lz4` files, so the answer from 2012 needed a brief update.

```
Depends: lz4
```

I also refactored the code slightly to prefer `grep -c` over `grep |  wc -l`

```
# FIXME: wrong numbers; see below
for f in /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages.lz4; do
    printf '%5d %s\n' $(lz4cat "$f" | grep -c '^Package: ') ${f##*/}
done | sort -rn
```

There are some duplicates in the output, so I guess a better number would be obtained by

```
for f in /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages.lz4; do
    lz4cat "$f" | awk -v file="${f##*/}" '/^Package: / && !p[$2]++ { ++n } END { print n, file}'
done | sort -rn
```

For Focal (20.04) with Universe enabled, this produces

```
53206 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
10768 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
9037 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
7345 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
6848 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
6090 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
4275 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
3373 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
813 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
198 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
142 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
102 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
93 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
86 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
```