# How many packages are there in ubuntu 22.04 repositories?

Tags: official-repositories

I mean main, restricted, universe, multiverse, updates, security updates and backports enabled. I think there are more than 60 thousand but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you want to know? You _could_ enable all of those repositories, `sudo apt update`, then process the output of `dpkg -l`.

Comment: Please use the search before asking questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/120630/how-many-packages-are-in-the-main-repository already has the answer (you need 20.04 installed though)

Comment: I am just curious. I think ubuntu has the largest repositories. I have xubuntu 22.04 and I was messing around with settings. Synaptic says there are 68100 packages available, including installed packages. Is that right?